# Why does code throw error when looped? My code works when I incremement index "by hand" but when I put in loop it fails

Tags: r, for-loop

I want to append values from one dataframe as column names to an another data frame.

I've written code that will produce one column at a time if I "manually" assigne index values:

```
df_searchtable <- data.frame(category = c("air", "ground", "ground", "air"), wiggy = c("soar", "trot", "dive", "gallop"))  
df_host <- data.frame(textcolum = c("run on the ground", "fly through the air"))

#create vector of categories
categroups <- as.character(unique(df_searchtable$category))


##### if I assign colum names one at a time using index numbers no prob:

group = categroups[1]
df_host[, group] <- NA


##### if I use a loop to assign the column names:

for (i in categroups) {
  group = categroups[i]
  df_host[, group] <- NA
}
```

the code fails, giving:

```
Error in [<-.data.frame(`*tmp*`, , group, value = NA) : 
missing values are not allowed in subscripted assignments of data frames
```

How can I get around this problem?

Comment: Note: you can avoid using `as.character()` to convert factors by specifying `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` in `data.frame()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple base R solution:

```
df_host[categroups] <- NA

df_host
            textcolum air ground
1   run on the ground  NA     NA
2 fly through the air  NA     NA
```

The problem with your loop is that you are looping through each element whereas your code assumes you are looping through `1, 2, ..., n`.

For instance:

```
for (i in categroups) {
  print(i)
  print(categroups[i])
}
[1] "air"
[1] NA
[1] "ground"
[1] NA
```

To fix your loop, you could do one of two things:

```
for (group in categroups) {
  df_host[, group] <- NA
}

# or
for (i in seq_along(categroups)) {
  group <- categroups[i]
  df_host[, group] <- NA
}
```

Comment: Sorry I've been away from this project for a while, but thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using [purrr's `map`](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/map.html).

```
bind_cols(df_host,
          map_dfc(categroups, 
                  function(group) tibble(!!group := rep(NA_real_, nrow(df_host)))))
```

Gives:

```
            textcolum air ground
1   run on the ground  NA     NA
2 fly through the air  NA     NA
```

- `map_dfc` maps over the input `categroups`, creates a single-column tibble for each one, and joins the newly created tibbles into a dataframe
- `bind_cols` joins the original dataframe to your new tibble

Alternatively you could use `walk`:

```
walk(categroups, function(group){df_host <<- mutate(df_host, !!group := rep(NA_real_, nrow(df_host)))})
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an ugly base R solution: create an empty matrix with the column names and `cbind` it to the second dataframe.

```
df_searchtable <- data.frame(category = c("air", "ground", "ground", "air"), 
                             wiggy = c("soar", "trot", "dive", "gallop"),
                             stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df_host <- data.frame(textcolum = c("run on the ground", "fly through the air"),
                      stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

cbind(df_host, 
      matrix(nrow = nrow(df_host), 
             ncol = length(unique(df_searchtable$category)), 
             dimnames = list(NULL, unique(df_searchtable$category))))
```

Result:

```
            textcolum air ground
1   run on the ground  NA     NA
2 fly through the air  NA     NA
```